# Do I need to configure the broker database as well as the preview database for the XPM web service?

Tags: experience-manager

As far as I understand it, XPM preview doesn't read or write anything to or from the main broker database - so there should be no need to have to configure the broker database in the `cd_storage_conf.xml` file of the Preview web service.

However, every example I've seen has both a preview database and a broker database configured. Is this just a cargo cult thing, or is there a real reason to have both?

Answer (score 7):

XPM does read from both databases.  We can deduce this because the Staging website has 2 modes:

- XPM disabled - uses regular DB
- XPM enabled - uses Session Preview DB

So it is not just a "cargo cult thing."

We can also see from the debug logs that XPM does some interesting triaging between the regular Broker and the Session Preview Broker:

```
2014-12-11 16:46:24,070 DEBUG ReadMethodHandler - Invoking read method: getPageURL on DAO: com.tridion.storage.persistence.JPAItemDAO@569bfd69
2014-12-11 16:46:24,070 DEBUG AbstractMethodHandler - Original publication ID for write method parameter [non_entity] is 10.
2014-12-11 16:46:24,070 DEBUG AbstractMethodHandler - Session-publication ID for write method parameter [non_entity] is 8.
2014-12-11 16:46:24,071 DEBUG ReadMethodHandler - Session DAO did not return a result, invoking original DAO method: getPageURL.
```

So it appears that when XPM is turned on on a given page, it stores and loads the items that are being session-previewed from the Session Preview DB and the items that don't need to be re-rendered come from the regular Broker and it merges the results from the two DBs.

Comment: That's indeed exactly what I recall Nick: the Session Preview DB acts as an overlay over the regular broker DB for *your* preview session.

Comment: Indeed, the staging web application (or the filter/module) needs to read from both. The question is specifically about the configuration of the web service. And there, my "cargo cult" question still stands.

Comment: Just tried setting the cd_preview_webservice without the main broker storage type. It throws an error, "Storage not available: No Data Access Object Factory" upon accessing a page in XPM mode.

Comment: You have to have a defaultStorageId, and I think it needs to point to a storage. (And a storage in a wrapper doesn't seem to count.) I've got it running with a filesystem storage pointing to NUL, but I don't know if there are use cases where it might break, or why.

Answer (score 3):

The "preview webservice" as you call it is the regular Content Delivery Web Service (sometimes also referred to as the "OData service") and it does (potentially) a lot more then just deploy session preview content to XPM:

- access FredHopper system configuration for SmartTarget
- access broker content via OData
- likely a hell of a lot more in the future seeing where things are going (note that this is more of a gut feeling from my side than anything confirmed by SDL R&D)

If in your scenario you are interested solely in serving deploying session preview content for XPM you will not need the configuration for the broker database; whether the software will work without it is an entirely different question (to my knowledge the preview webservice needs a correctly configured cd_deployer_conf.xml even though it does not do regular deployments but who knows how all of it works under the hood of the public API? Certainly not me anyway )

Long story short: if you don't need it try without it but remember that is is generally riskier to lead then to follow...

Comment: Heard a rumour that the deployer config is needed because of the TCDL transforms (which must then presumably be executed as the content is stored in the preview database).

Comment: Ah yes of course! Is this used even when the target language is REL and no deploy time transformations take place?